# URL::to('/') echoed as string (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I'm working with my project which get new orders and append to DOM with jQuery.

**jQuery**

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'{{URL::to('/')}}/orders',
    success:function(data)
    {                           
      let obj = JSON.parse(data)
      let ordersDiv = $('#ordersDiv');
      let queueCount = $('#queueCount');

      queueCount.html(obj.count);
      ordersDiv.html(obj.data);

    }
  });
}, 15000);
```

**Controller**

```
//some code here

$data .= "<a class=\"example-image-link\" 
             href=\"{{URL::to('/')}}/users/uploads/profiles/{{strlen($biker- 
              >picture_file_path)>0?$biker>picture_file_path:'avatar.png'}}\">
             <img src=\"URL::to('/')/users/uploads/profiles/$biker- 
             >picture_file_path:.'avatar.png'\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" 
             title=\"HiBes Biker\">
            </a>";
//more code here
```

My problem is that I'm getting this result:

```
<a href=\"{URL::to('\/')}\/order-details\/3159\">Details<\/a>
```

I expect a result something like this:

```
<a href=\"http://127.0.0.1:8000/order-details\/3159\">Details<\/a>
```

Comment: Is your jQuery code in a `.php` file or a `.js` file?

Comment: .php i store in under my view,  does it affect the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your URLs still contain the placeholders is you are building HTML in your controller, not your view.

Ideally, you should switch this logic into the view, where the `{{ $var }}` syntax will work.

Create a new blade file `bikerimage.blade.php`

```
@foreach($bikers as $biker)
    <a class="example-image-link"
       href="{{URL::to('/')}}/users/uploads/profiles/{{ $biker->picture_file_path ?: 'avatar.png' }}">
        <img src="{{ URL::to('/')}}/users/uploads/profiles/{{ $biker->picture_file_path ?: 'avatar.png' }}"
             data-toggle="tooltip"
             title="HiBes Biker"
        >
    </a>
@endforeach
```

Then in your controller, you can do something like

```php
 //some code here

$data = view('partials/bikerimage.blade.php', ['bikers' => $bikers])->render();

return [
    'html' => $data,
];
```

This means you can still return the data as part of an ajax call, without having to build HTML in your controller.

Comment: i bind it in controller because i am sending an ajax request to that controller and it will return that html data, but the url is echoed as string not converting to what im expecting

Comment: @Franz Even if this is a ajax request you should still be able to use blade template and return it in the controller action instead of building as a string. You can use the `view()` helper to return a view from the controller action.